# Spacing for Python Format Multiple Variables

Tags: python, format

I was wondering if anyone out there knew the proper spacing for a multi-variable string format such as:

```
"My name is {NAME}, and today I ate {LUNCH}.".format(
    NAME='G.G. Allen',LUNCH='buttery pancakes and 3 bacon strips')
```

Comment: What do you mean by proper spacing? Your code works.

Comment: @gtlambert yes just wanted to know proper spacing.

Comment: I would suggest a space before `LUNCH`. After that, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many different possibilities are syntactically valid. If you want something easy on the eye, I'd suggest a line break before LUNCH, and aligning NAME and LUNCH together vertically.

The convention is typically that there is no space before and after the `=` for a keyword argument (unlike an assignment).

Also note that [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to restrict the line length at 79 characters.

```
"My name is {NAME}, and today I ate {LUNCH}.".format(
             NAME='G.G. Allen',
             LUNCH='buttery pancakes and 3 bacon strips')
```

Comment: Actually it's 79 characters (and 72 for docstrings/comments).

Answer (score 0):

Even as per python's official style guide your code is valid (just keep a space before LUNCH as gtlambert has pointed out). Please check [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for other recommendations.